# Unable to set JVM arguments for Playframework binary?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I used `activator stage` to generate a binary for an playframework (2.3.9) app (the app's name is `hello`).

Then I tried to tune JVM arguments to start it like this:

```
 ./target/universal/stage/bin/hello -Dhttp.port=7878 -Xms900M -Xmx2000m -server
```

But it returns `Bad application path` error:

```
Bad application path: -Xms900M
```

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

P.S. The operation system is CentOS. Below is some information :

```
 del in ~/hello
○ → echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/

 del in ~/hello
○ → echo $CLASSPATH 
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45//lib/tools.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45//lib/dt.jar

 del in ~/hello
○ → lsb_release -ic    
Distributor ID: CentOS
Codename:   Final
```

Comment: @m-z I'm using CentOS. More information has just been added in the question.

Comment: Duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090243/how-to-set-heap-size-in-play-activator, but I wouldn't close it, since the question is phrased so differently.

Answer (score 0):

After trying, I found `-J-` prefix works for JVM args

```
 del in ~/hello
○ → ./target/universal/stage/bin/hello -Dhttp.port=7878 -J-Xms2000m -J-Xmx2000m
```