# How to increase stack size of play framework activator?

Tags: macos, scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I'm developing play framework application on OS X.
recently my app started getting 'stackOverflowError' while `activator dist` So I want to increase stack size though I don't know how.
It seems working with `export PLAY_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss4M"` If I don't use `sudo` to run `activator dist`.But I need it be runnable with `sudo` for some reason.

is there any way to achieve this?

I've already tried appending `jvm.memory=-Xss4M` to `application.conf` and `javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Xss4m")` in `build.sbt` which does not work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set heap size in play/activator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090243/how-to-set-heap-size-in-play-activator)

Comment: I've already checked the question and answer. those setting won't be enabled in `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` ignores existing environment variables (see `man sudo`). You can try one of these two variations:

```
sudo PLAY_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss4M" activator dist
```

or

```
export PLAY_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss4M"
sudo -E activator dist
```