# Increasing memory of Play for Scala/Activator ~run

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm running Play for Scala, and need to increase the heap/memory size as it runs out of memory when compiling.

I see the following in `activator.bat`:

```
rem TODO Check if there are existing mem settings in JAVA_OPTS/CFG_OPTS and use those instead of the below
for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%v in ("%JAVA_VERSION%") do (
    set MAJOR=%%v
    set MINOR=%%w
    set BUILD=%%x

    set META_SIZE=-XX:MetaspaceSize=64M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M
    if "!MINOR!" LSS "8" (
      set META_SIZE=-XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
    )

    set MEM_OPTS=!META_SIZE!
 )
```

What is MAJOR, MINOR? Which one should I change? How to verify that Play is actually allocating the extra memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to modify activator.bat to increase the memory. Just set anyone of these environment variables

```
SBT_OPTS
ACTIVATOR_OPTS
JAVA_OPTS
```

[How to set heap size in play/activator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090243/how-to-set-heap-size-in-play-activator)

Once your play application is running, run jconsole (its in the bin directory of your jdk) and monitor the heap size using that.

http://karunsubramanian.com/java/5-not-so-easy-ways-to-monitor-the-heap-usage-of-your-java-application/

Comment: Based on your links, I'm running `activator ~run -mem=3000` but in jconsole I see `Maximum heap size: 7,431,168 kbytes` why is that?